# name is not defined python when it should be

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, oop

Heres an example of the type of error i'm getting with relevant code:

```
class One:
   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def funcOne(self):
      two.funcTwo()

class Two:
   def __init__(self):
      one = One()
      one.funcOne()

   def funcTwo(self):
      print('we got here')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   two = Two()
```

However, I'm getting thrown this error. I'm probably missing something very obvious so this should be simple but I just can't understand it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    two = Two()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.py", line 11, in __init__
    one.funcOne()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.py", line 6, in funcOne
    two.funcTwo()
NameError: name 'two' is not defined
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are calling to two in funcOne(), which is not defined

Comment: `two` is not yet defined at the time when the line `two.funcTwo()` is executed.

Comment: but two was defined in the if statement at the bottom

Comment: @FaizanShah no, `two` is defined once `Two()` has finished.

Comment: Oh that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

`two` is not yet defined at the time when the line `two.funcTwo()` is executed.

The last line of your program

```
two = Two()
```

says "make an instance of Two and assign it to the name `two`."

In the process of "make an instance of Two", you try and call `two.funcTwo()`. But until "make an instance of Two" has *finished*, it won't be assigned to the name `two`.

Answer (score -1):

The `two` variable in funcOne is uninitialized